# Tracking Emails using Mailtrack trough emails sent using Google Script Editor and trigger

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-api, tracking

I was trying to send an email programatically using the script I created using Google Script Editor for spreadsheet,

```
function sendEmail(){
    GmailApp.sendEmail('email', subject , body, { htmlBody: htmlTemplate() });
}
```

this function will automatically execute using a trigger (i.e, if new row has been added to a spreadsheet). Now, I added mailTrack addon to my gmail to track if someone already read or seen the emails I sent. The addon only works for emails that has been sent manually.

So my question is, is there a way to call a gmail addon to script editor then attach it along with the htmlBody to track my email? or is there a way to activate this addon to script editor before sending an email? Is my question confusing?

Comment: Apps Script doesn't know what add-ons you've installed. If you have an account with mailTrack, you could ask them if they have an API endpoint from which you could request the needed item to include in your email. They may or may not have something configured to support that.

Comment: Thanks man, I've been pulling my hair on this one. I've been browsing the apps-script documentation for gmailApp addons, and yeah you're right functions for getting the addons doesn't exist yet. I'll try contacting the mailTracker team for an API endpoint.

Comment: Any progress on in? I need same thing.